# c++ tidy linker error

Tags: c++, tidy

I am new to c++ and I have the following problem:

files:
 - main.cpp
 - utils.h
 - utils.cpp

When I am doing:

g++ -c -std=c++11 utils.cpp  (compiles)
g++ -c -std=c++11 main.cpp (compiles)

when I try to link:

g++ -o main.o utils.o

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
>   utils.o: In function `clean_html(std::string const&)':
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to`tidyCreate'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to`tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to`tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to`tidyOptSetValue'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `tidyOptSetValue'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to`tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `tidyOptSetBool'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to`tidyOptSetInt'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `tidyParseString'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to`tidyCleanAndRepair'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to `tidySaveBuffer'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to`tidyBufFree'
>   utils.cpp:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `tidyRelease'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In utils.cpp I have a function clean_html. When I remove this function the code is linked with success.

I am using gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC) .

Tidy is installed via fedora repos using:
Package libtidy-devel-0.99.0-28.20091203.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libtidy-0.99.0-28.20091203.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version

Edit:

Forgot to mention:
 - I include tidy.h using
    #include

tidy.h is at /usr/include/tidy.h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). You probably missed to specify `-ltidy` on linking stage.

Comment: can you show the link command. You're likely missing the `-l` option to link the tidy library.

Comment: @geert3 I addded the link command. What is the library name to add to -l? And how do I figure this out?

Comment: Ok I fifure this out.
Thanks @geert3. I had to add -ltidy to the link command.If you want add an answer to accept

Comment: It is likely `/usr/lib/libtidy.so`, so you would need `g++ -ltidy -o main.o utils.o`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `-ltidy` to your link command.